# Missing query parameters in Tauri + Nuxt3 app

Tags: nuxt3, tauri

I am building a simple desktop app using Tauri + Nuxt3.

After the user clicks on a button I need the app to redirect to an existing page with a query parameter (id). Code is as follows:

In the list page (the one with the button):

```
const { $router } = useNuxtApp()

function editCustomer(customer) {
  $router.push({ path: '/customer/new', query: { customer: customer } })
}

<q-btn label="Edit" @click="editCustomer(customer)" />
```

The ~/pages/customer/new.vue:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const route = useRoute()

const customer = ref(route.query.customer ? route.query.customer : '')
console.log(customer.value)
console.log(route.query)
```

Both console.log-s output empty objects.

I have also tried creating custom router.js file in the root directory, adding a custom named route and switching the request from path: to name: as well as query: {} to params: {} - still empty objects. Another thing I have tried is using the navigateTo() util - same result. Finally, I tried using the directory structure for optional parameters like:

```
pages/
 -customer/
 --new/
 ---[[customer]].vue
```

which still matches routes with and without parameters, but the route.query remains empty.

Another thing I have noticed: When the page redirects, if I right click and "Reload" the page, the route.query parameters are there.

I suspect I am missing something simple, but just cannot put my finger on it.